# techniques in git grep and vim

Tags: git, vim, grep

I code in vim.

I use git; and love git grep.

Does anyone have a particularly nice set of techniques / scripts for using git grep inside of vim?

Comment: +1 because I didn't realize how valuable `git grep` was before!! (I was using `ack-grep`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do have this [VIM extension](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Git_grep) (created by **Timo Hirvonen** back in 2006!)

> `git grep <pattern>` searches for a pattern in a currently selected git branch.
> This adds `:G <pattern>` command to run the command from within Vim.
>
> ```ts
> func GitGrep(...)
>   let save = &grepprg
>   set grepprg=git\ grep\ -n\ $*
>   let s = 'grep!'
>   for i in a:000
>     let s = s . ' ' . i
>   endfor
>   exe s
>   copen
>   let &grepprg = save
> endfun
> command -nargs=? G call GitGrep(<f-args>)
> ```

As noted by [dafnahaktana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1019140/dafnahaktana) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415237/techniques-in-git-grep-and-vim/2415257#comment123908436_2415257):

> `let s = 'grep'` is replaced with `let s = '!grep'`, to avoid automatically jumping to the first match (why would I want to?).
> And also add the command `copen` after the command `exe s`, so that the matching list automatically opens.

Then:

> You can also limit searching to files matching a pattern (Git will do the pattern matching):
>
> ```
> :G <pattern> -- '*.c'
> ```
>
> Additions:
>
> The following addition will run `git grep` on the word under the cursor when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> is pressed.
>
> ```ts
> func GitGrepWord()
>    normal! "zyiw"
>    call GitGrep('-w -e ', getreg('z'))
>  endf
> nmap <C-x>G :call GitGrepWord()<CR>
> ```

Comment: This is awesome. Can you post more / everything you have on this? Even if you post 9 "useless" vim/git-grep interface lines, it's worth it for the 1 trick that I do use.

Comment: @anon: added another Vim plugin, as requested (see my second answer)

Comment: When I use, this GitGrep, it first hides my vim screen, shows the result of git grep, then after I press a key, throws me back into vim at the first line -- is there a way to just jump to the first line (and hide the git grep output)

Comment: @anon: I am not sure, but I have found another Vim Git encapsulation thatat could be worth checking out. See my third answer below.

Comment: wow, -w does "word" matching as it rejects a match to a subpart of a word? that's amazing. this deserves more +1

Comment: @anon: true (for the `-w` option), although `git grep` has many more options (http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-grep.html)

Comment: in `GitGrep`, I replace `let s = 'grep'` with `let s = '!grep'` to avoid automatically jumping to the first match (why would I want to?). and also add the command `copen` after the command `exe s` so that the matching list automatically opens

Comment: @dafnahaktana Interesting. Could you edit the answer to include those improvements?

Comment: @dafnahaktana Perfect. Thank you for the edit. I have edited the answer to include your comment for more visibility.

Answer (score 9):

Check also  [**fugitive.vim** - A Git wrapper so awesome, it should be illegal](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2975)
(that is its official tag-line ;) ), from **[Tim Pope](http://www.vim.org/account/profile.php?user_id=9012)** (see the [Git repo project](http://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/master/plugin/fugitive.vim)):

It includes, amongst many other commands, one for a `git grep`:

```
call s:command("-bar -bang -nargs=? -complete=customlist,s:EditComplete Ggrep :execute s:Grep(<bang>0,<q-args>)")
call s:command("-bar -bang -nargs=* -complete=customlist,s:EditComplete Glog :execute s:Log('grep<bang>',<f-args>)")

function! s:Grep(bang,arg) abort
  let grepprg = &grepprg
  let grepformat = &grepformat
  let cd = exists('*haslocaldir') && haslocaldir() ? 'lcd ' : 'cd '
  let dir = getcwd()
  try
    execute cd.'`=s:repo().tree()`'
    let &grepprg = s:repo().git_command('--no-pager', 'grep', '-n')
    let &grepformat = '%f:%l:%m'
    exe 'grep! '.a:arg
    let list = getqflist()
    for entry in list
      if bufname(entry.bufnr) =~ ':'
        let entry.filename = s:repo().translate(bufname(entry.bufnr))
        unlet! entry.bufnr
      elseif a:arg =~# '\%(^\| \)--cached\>'
        let entry.filename = s:repo().translate(':0:'.bufname(entry.bufnr))
        unlet! entry.bufnr
      endif
    endfor
    call setqflist(list,'r')
    if !a:bang && !empty(list)
      return 'cfirst'
    else
      return ''
    endif
  finally
    let &grepprg = grepprg
    let &grepformat = grepformat
    execute cd.'`=dir`'
  endtry
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2):

Still in the same set of Git encapsulation (including `git grep`), you have:

[**MinSCM : An abstract front-end for Mercurial/Git/Bazaar**](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2637) , from [Takeshi NISHIDA](http://www.vim.org/account/profile.php?user_id=12324):
See his [Git repo](http://bitbucket.org/ns9tks/vim-minscm/)

[alt text http://bitbucket.org/ns9tks/vim-minscm/wiki/log.png](http://bitbucket.org/ns9tks/vim-minscm/wiki/log.png)

```
:MinSCMGrep[!]                  (Default mapping: \sg)
```

> Searches for specified pattern and creates a |quickfix| list.
>
> Used SCM commands ~
>
> - hg  : `grep -n`
> - git : `grep -n -e`
> - bzr : (unavailable)

Answer (score 1):

You also have this set of vim commands, from the Git project **[git grep vim](http://github.com/tjennings/git-grep-vim/blob/master/plugin/git-grep.vim)**, from [**tjennings**](http://github.com/tjennings).
(inspired from the [ack.vim : Plugin for the Perl module / CLI script 'ack'](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2572) from [Miles Sterrett](http://www.vim.org/account/profile.php?user_id=15956))

```
let g:gitgrepprg="git\\ grep\\ -n"

function! GitGrep(args)
    let grepprg_bak=&grepprg
    exec "set grepprg=" . g:gitgrepprg
    execute "silent! grep " . a:args
    botright copen
    let &grepprg=grepprg_bak
    exec "redraw!"
endfunction

function! GitGrepAdd(args)
    let grepprg_bak=&grepprg
    exec "set grepprg=" . g:gitgrepprg
    execute "silent! grepadd " . a:args
    botright copen
    let &grepprg=grepprg_bak
    exec "redraw!"
endfunction

function! LGitGrep(args)
    let grepprg_bak=&grepprg
    exec "set grepprg=" . g:gitgrepprg
    execute "silent! lgrep " . a:args
    botright lopen
    let &grepprg=grepprg_bak
    exec "redraw!"
endfunction

function! LGitGrepAdd(args)
    let grepprg_bak=&grepprg
    exec "set grepprg=" . g:gitgrepprg
    execute "silent! lgrepadd " . a:args
    botright lopen
    let &grepprg=grepprg_bak
    exec "redraw!"
endfunction

command! -nargs=* -complete=file GitGrep call GitGrep(<q-args>)
command! -nargs=* -complete=file GitGrepAdd call GitGrepAdd(<q-args>)
command! -nargs=* -complete=file LGitGrep call LGitGrep(<q-args>)
command! -nargs=* -complete=file LGitGrepAdd call LGitGrepAdd(<q-args>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a [gist](https://gist.github.com/joehillen/3626719) that open results from `git grep` in a quickfix window to jump around:

```
<C-x><C-x> runs grep for the word under the cursor
:G <word> runs grep 
:Gi <word> runs grep as case-insensitive
```

Just add the content of the gist to your `~/.vimrc` file